# GZ Compressing an XML sitemap file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, gzip, sitemap

I have a PHP script that generates a dynamic PHP sitemap from my site's database to an xml file using `fopen()` and `fwrite()`.

How can I compress this file using GZ compression dynamically as I write it?

I tried `fwrite()`-ing strings that I ran through `gzcompress()` into the file and renaming it ".xml.gz", but it doesn't seem the file it;s creating is a well-fromed archive.

Answer (score 4):

Not using fopen and fwrite but  [`gzopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) and [`gzwrite()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) should do the trick for you.

From the manual:

```
# Sample #1 gzwrite() example
<?php
$string = 'Some information to compress';
$gz = gzopen('somefile.gz','w9');
gzwrite($gz, $string);
gzclose($gz);
?>
```

If i understood correctly

Comment: I think he wants to compress the source code but only he knows what he wants lol :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a quote from the php site that we all should keep in mind.

> Take Heed 07-Nov-2010 08:50 Read the description of gzwrite() very
>   carefully.  If the 'length' option is not specified, then the input
>   data will have slashes stripped on systems where magic quotes are
>   enabled.  This is important information to know when compressing
>   files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzwrite.php

Comment: Ha, and I thought I knew all the reasons to hate magic_quotes... Yet another atrocity. They were a Very Bad Idea if I ever saw one...